# Is SceneKit's SCNMatrix4 stored as column or row-major?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, opengl-es, scenekit

The source of my confusion is the documentation on [SCNMatrix4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmatrix4) from Apple:

> SceneKit uses matrices to represent coordinate space transformations,
>   which in turn can represent the combined position, rotation or
>   orientation, and scale of an object in three-dimensional space.
>   SceneKit matrix structures are in **row-major order**, so they are
>   **suitable for passing to shader programs or OpenGL APIs** that accept matrix parameters.

This seems contradictory since OpenGL uses column-major transformation matrices!

In general the documentation of Apple on this topic is poor:

- [GLKMatrix4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/glkmatrix4-pce) does not talk about column vs. row major at all, but
  I am certain from all discussions online that GLKMatrix is plain and
  simple column-major.
- simd_float4x4 does not talk about the
  topic, but at least the variable names make it clear that it is
  stored as columns:

From `simd/float.h`:

```
typedef struct { simd_float4 columns[4]; } simd_float4x4;
```

Some discussion online about SCNMatrix4 talk as if SCNMatrix4 is different from GLKMatrix4, but looking at the code for SCNMatrix4 give some hints that it might just be column-order as expected:

```
/* Returns a transform that translates by '(tx, ty, tz)':
 * m' =  [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; tx ty tz 1]. */
NS_INLINE SCNMatrix4 SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(float tx, float ty, float tz) {
    SCNMatrix4 m = SCNMatrix4Identity;
    m.m41 = tx;
    m.m42 = ty;
    m.m43 = tz;
    return m;
}
```

So is `SCNMatrix4` row-major (storing translations in `m14`, `m24`, `m34`) or column-major (storing translations in `m41`, `m42`, `m43`)?

Comment: Also very important that causes significant confusion as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435756/xcode-simd-issue-with-translation-and-rotation-matrix-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SCNMatrix4` stores the translation in `m41`, `m42` and `m43`, as is `GLKMatrix4`. This little Playground confirms it as well as its definition.

```
import SceneKit

let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1, 2, 3)

translation.m41
// 1
translation.m42
// 2
translation.m43
// 3
```

I have no idea why this is wrong in the documentation though, probably just a mistake.