# Xcode simd - issue with Translation and Rotation Matrix Example

Tags: matrix, scenekit, arkit, simd

Not only is using column-major vs row-major counter-intuitive, Apple's documentation on "Working with Matrices" further exacerbates the confusion by their examples of "constructing" a "Translate Matrix" and a "Rotation  Matrix" in 2D.

**Translate Matrix Per Apple's Documentation ()**

> Translate A translate matrix takes the following form:
>
> ```
> 1  0  0
> 0  1  0 
> tx ty 1
> ```
>
> The simd library provides constants for identity matrices (matrices
>   with ones along the diagonal, and zeros elsewhere). The 3 x 3 Float
>   identity matrix is matrix_identity_float3x3.
>
> The following function returns a simd_float3x3 matrix using the
>   specified tx and ty translate values by setting the elements in an
>   identity matrix:
>
> ```
> func makeTranslationMatrix(tx: Float, ty: Float) -> simd_float3x3 {
>     var matrix = matrix_identity_float3x3
>
>     matrix[0, 2] = tx
>     matrix[1, 2] = ty
>
>     return matrix 
> }
> ```

**My Issue with it**

The line of code `matrix[0, 2] = tx` sets the value of the first column and the third row to `tx`. `let translationMatrix = makeTranslationMatrix(tx: 1, ty: 3)` and printing out the 2nd column `print(translationMatrix.columns.2)` will yield `float3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. I am very confused regarding why it is the last row that contains the translation values, rather than the column. This convention is not used when using `SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation` and creating a `simd_float4x4` out of the `SCNMatrix4` object.

```
var A = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1,2,3)
var Asimd = simd_float4x4(A)

A.m41 // 1
A.m42 // 2
A.m43 // 3
A.m44 // 1

Asimd.columns.3 // float4(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0)
```

Both `SCNMatrix4` and `simd_float4x4` follow the *column major* naming convention. In the 2D example from Apple, it is the last row that contains the translation values, whereas with `SCNMatrix4` and converting to `simd_float4x4`, it is the last column that contains the translation values. Apple's example seems to be doing the same with the Rotation Matrices as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: _“and printing out the 2nd column `print(translationMatrix.columns.2)`”_  You aren't printing out the 2nd column here, you're printing the **3rd column**.  These are 0-based indexes (as is common in programming), so the `0` is the 1st; `1` is the 2nd, & `2` is the 3rd.  The `float3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` you get as a result isn't related to the matrix values you set (in the 1st & 2nd columns)— it's the 3rd column, which still has the identity values.

Comment: _(An identity 3x3 matrix has `1.0` diagonally in the `[0,0]`, `[1,1]`, & `[2,2]` spots, and `0.0` everywhere else.)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be confusing, yes.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_matrices?language=objc#2970126) you mentions makes the following computation:

> `let translatedVector = positionVector * translationMatrix`

Note that *the matrix is on the right side of the multiplication*.
You are probably used to the notation `b = M * a` but if you take the transpose you get `b' = a' * M'` which is what the sample does.

In SIMD there's no way to differentiate a vector from its transpose (`b` from `b'`) and the library allows you to make the multiplication in both ways:

```
static simd_float3 SIMD_CFUNC simd_mul(simd_float3x3 __x, simd_float3 __y);
static simd_float3 SIMD_CFUNC simd_mul(simd_float3 __x,  simd_float3x3 __y) { return simd_mul(simd_transpose(__y), __x); }
```

Comment: That explains a lot - however, I am not sure I understand the statement "In SIMD there's no way to differentiate a vector from its transpose (b from b')" - what exactly do you mean? I expect SIMD will multiply any matrices you specify, as long as the dimensions agree. Are you telling me that if initially the dimensions don't agree like a `4x4 times 1x4` matrix it will try to automatically transpose the second and turn it into a `4x4 times 4x1 = 4x1`?

Comment: In SIMD there's no difference between `mat4x1` and `mat1x4`, they are both `vec4`. As a result the same `vec4` variable can be used on both sides of the multiplication, so you have to be extra cautious about the convention you use.

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that in the first form `simd_mul(«matrix», «vector»)` the vector is interpreted as a column vector, while in the latter form `simd_mul(«vector», «matrix»)` the vector is interpreted as a row vector.  _Source: Apple's documentation comments at the top of <simd/matrix.h>._