# What do values in ARKit transform matrices represent?

Tags: ios, iphone, arkit

Right now I am trying to understand the values within an ARKit transform matrix so I can quantify the movements of my SCNNode. From a previous post on stack overflow I have learned that the matrix contains information regarding the node's current translation, scale, rotation, and position.

What I am not understanding is which values are specifically associated with those four things. For example I have figured out that the first element of the 3rd column represents an X (horizontal) movement on the screen and the 2nd value of the 3rd column represents a Y (vertical) movement. But other than that I'm not sure what the rest of the values in the matrix mean.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In a transformation matrix, the **translation** information is in the last column. 
Given a transformation matrix, you can extract the translation from the last column as below:

```
let translation = SCNVector3(transform.columns.3.x, transform.columns.3.y, transform.columns.3.z)
```

Rotation and scaling use the first three columns and are more complex. 
**Scale** is the length of the first three column vectors, and to extract the **rotation** you need to divide the first three column vectors by the scaling factors just mentioned.
You can refer to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati) for a better understanding of scale and rotation and how to extract them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I now realize this after looking at some of my old graphics notes. For ARKit however, the transform matrix is in row-major order. So if you were to transpose all of the information you told me in your post, then it'd be applicable to ARKit transform matrices.

Comment: @NFarrell good point. this link was useful for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435756/xcode-simd-issue-with-translation-and-rotation-matrix-example

Comment: Yea that helps for sure. I was trying to quantify the rotations of my SCNNode as it moved around through using the transform matrix but it turns out that SCNNode's have a eulerAngle property that give the angles of rotation from each axis so i didn't have to do any math. Much easier and saved a lot of headaches

Answer (score 0):

MohammadRF's answered cleared things up for me the best. However, ARKit's matrices are in row-major order so if you were to transpose the matrices from the information he gave then it would apply to ARKit.